# Access web server externally

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, webserver, web, jboss

I have a JBoss server running on my macbook. I can access it via:

```
https://localhost:8443/appname/login.do
```

I would like to access it via my external IP address:

```
https://102.115.XXX.XXX:8443/appname/login.do
```

However I just get a page time out.

I have changed my JBoss settings as follows:

**standalone.xml**

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <any-ipv4-address/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <any-ipv4-address/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

So I am guessing it's my router that is blocking access?

**Question**

What do I need to change to allow external access to my server?

**More info:**

I am using a TP-Link Archer 2 router AC750.

[image]

[image]

My internal IP address:

[image]

I have tried with my port forwarding set to accept 443 to 8443, but no luck:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to access `https://102.115.XXX.XXX:8443/appname/login.do` from your internal network or from an external network?

Comment: External network.  I am using my phone on a mobile network

Comment: You haven't port forwarded `8443`

Comment: Yes. I added port forwarding of 8443 to 8443, and tried to access it with https://102.115.XXX.XXX:8443/appname/login.do. Which did not work, the browser just eventually times out.

Comment: Your router screenshot does not show 8443 ... it shows 443

Comment: Yes, that's the default settings.  I have since tried with adding 8443. Apologies for not being clear.

Comment: You should edit your question and add a screenshot showing your 8443 settings. Also confirm that 192.168.0 110 is the internal network IP-address of your JBoss server (e.g. include a screenshot of running `ipconfig | findstr IPv4` or `ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet "` on your JBoss server)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, thanks for the advise. I have added what you said. p.s. I could not run `ipconfig | findstr IPv4` or `ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet "`, but have added my internal IP above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Ports

You have forwarded external port 443 to internal port 8443

This means from the outside you need to connect
to   `https://102.115.XXX.XXX:443/appname/login.do`
not `https://102.115.XXX.XXX:8443/appname/login.do`

The router will change the port number to 8443 for the internal leg of the connection.

Port forwarding operates on pairs of addresses+ports like this

```
+--------+
|External|
|Device  |
+--------+
    | XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:mmmmm (random source port)
    |
    v 102.115.XXX.XXX:443 (fixed destination port)
+--------+
|your    |.....Config = forward inbound TCP 443 to device 192.168.0.110 port 8443
|router  |
+--------+ 
    |  |  192.168.0.1:nnnnnn (random source-port)
    |  |
    |  `----------------------.
    |                         |
    v 192.168.0.105:8443      v 192.167.0.110:8443 (destination addresses+ports)
+--------+                  +--------+
|your    |                  |mystery |
|Macbook |                  |device  |
+--------+                  +--------+
```

Note that the port-forwarding rules specify **one** destination IP-address, not a range of IP-addresses. This destination IP-address **must** exactly match the IP-address of your JBoss server.

## Internal addresses

You say your internal address is 192.168.0.**105** but your port forwarding is to 192.168.0.**110**.

There are many internal addresses, not just one, so you need to be clear about which internal address you refer to:

- the internal address of the router
- the internal address of your JBoss server
- the internal address of a desktop PC (if the JBoss server is a different computer)

## Firewalls

Computers such as MacBooks can have internal firewalls as part of the operating system. These can be configured to block incoming connections from other devices or network-address ranges. This might prevent a connection being established via your router.

## Interfaces

A computer can have many network interfaces, it may have one or more ethernet adapters, a WiFi adapter and others as well as a loopback adapter. Each of these may have one or more IPV4 adresses as well as one or more IPV6 addresses. On a Mac I believe you should be able to see all these by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> together and typing `terminal`. Then in the terminal window type `ifconfig` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

## Bindings

Programs such as JBoss can usually be configured to specifiy which network interfaces they "bind" to. This affect which of the potentially many IPV$ addresses above can be used to connect to the JBoss service. The JBoss service is considered to be "listening" to certain addresses and ports. You may be able to see which programs are listening on which addresses and ports by typing something like `netstat -anp` into a terminal window (as above). I am not a Mac user so you may need to check the command details for the Mac.

Comment: Hi @RedGrittyBrick, thanks for the reply.  I have tried that, but the browser just times out.   (I am using my phone browser off the local network).

Comment: @Richard: What about the internal address issue?

Comment: Just tested. Internal access is fine if I use `localhost`. But if I try use the internal IP address (`https://192.160.0.105:8443/...`), then the browser just hangs.

Comment: I see your comment above about `105` vs `110`. Let me test it....

Comment: I am confused (excuse my ignorance ). The router has `192.168.0.110` for its default port forwarding IP addresses, so I guess that correct. But if I look at my network settings, the macbook says my internal address is `192.168.0.105`. If I try access the JBoss server internally, what IP address should I use?

Comment: From any computer (PC, Mac, phone, etc) connected to your internal network (by Ethernet cable or WiFi) you can use 192.168.0.105.

Comment: Thanks.  Now I can get `https://192.168.0.105:8443/` to work. But the external IP `https://102.115.XXX.XXX:443/` says `site can't be reached`. My router port forwarding is `443 -> 192.168.0.110 -> 8443`.

Comment: @Richard: You need to change the port forwarding from 110 to 105

Comment: My router only allows one IP address, not a range in the `port forwarding` section. Do I need to set it somewhere else?

Comment: @Richard: See page 41 of your [router manual](https://static.tp-link.com/Archer_C2(EU)_V3_UG_1475912206443h.pdf)

Comment: Thanks  RedGrittyBrick, but that manual does not correspond to my router (maybe it's a different version). Mine is like this: https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/134/.  I am trying to find the answer on how to set a range of IPs still.

Comment: I changed my port forward to:  `443 192.168.0.105 8443 TCP or UDP Enabled` and it works.  Thanks for the help.